# DDoS attacks are killing all my services

Tags: linux, iptables, ddos

I've a few servers running as ssh proxy, someone started to DDOS me, i've installed ddos deflate and apf. The traffic made by ddos downgrade from 10 MB/s to 1 MB/s but it still make my users kick from my servers. My question is: if I make a rule to monitor all my traffic and lock new connections when someone start ddos will work? I mean, lock new connections and keep the others running!

Answer (score 2):

If the DDoS is saturating your bandwidth, there's *nothing* you can do at the server-level to protect yourself. You'd have to contact whoever your upstream provider is to help mitigate the attack.

That said, 1 MB/s is hardly a DDoS. You could probably use iptables to rate-limit things, but depending on the traffic pattern it could be hard to protect against.

Comment: Im just using SSH, theres a way to limit it with APF? Max connections pet IP, max package size per IP?